# Using different projection functions in Hibernate criteria API based in Dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I want to use a standard deviation projection in a query that Im constructing using the criteria API. I can do something simply like this

```
public class StdDevProjection extends AggregateProjection {

    public StdDevProjection(String propertyName) {
        super("stddev", propertyName);
    }

    public Type[] getTypes(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    throws HibernateException {
        return new Type[] { Hibernate.DOUBLE };
   }
```

}

and then I can use it with my criteria as:

```
myCriteriea.setProjection(new StdDevProjection(myproperty));
```

Thats all good. But my problem is that I use HSQLDB for any db unit tests etc, whereas we use Oracle for deployment. The stddev function works perfectly in oracle, but its not there in HSQLDB. HSQLDB has stddev_pop and stddev_samp . So is there someway I can use a different function based on the dialect.

I maybe can extend the HSQL dialect to register the "stddev" to the appropriate HSQL function, but then im not sure how to use an hsql function in a query constructed using the Criteria API.

Any help would be gret.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dialect is the right approach (although I've got to say that using different database engines for testing vs deployment seems a bit iffy). You can do the following:

1. Extend HSQL dialect and use `registerFunction()` to register an appropriate `stddev` implementation.
2. Override `toSqlString()` method in your `StdDevProjection` class and have Dialect render function name.

Something like:

```
public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, int loc, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
  Dialect dialect = criteriaQuery.getFactory().getDialect();
  SQLFunction function = (SQLFunction) dialect.getFunctions().get(this.aggregate);
  //TODO: throw an exception if function is not registered

  //create function argument array
  List functionArgs = new ArrayList(1);
  functionArgs.add(criteriaQuery.getColumn(criteria, propertyName));

  return new StringBuffer()
    .append(function.render(functionArgs, criteriaQuery.getFactory()))
    .append(" as y").append(loc).append('_')
    .toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StdDevProjection extends AggregateProjection {
/**
 * 
 */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7056189336427534748L;
    private String aggregateName = null;
    public StdDevProjection(String propertyName) {
        super("stddev", propertyName);
        this.aggregateName = "stddev";
    }
    @Override
    public Type[] getTypes(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    throws HibernateException {
        return new Type[] { Hibernate.DOUBLE };
    }
    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, int loc, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
            throws HibernateException {
        Dialect dialect = criteriaQuery.getFactory().getDialect();
        SQLFunction function = (SQLFunction)dialect.getFunctions().get(this.aggregateName);
        if(function == null) {
            throw new HibernateException("Couldnt find function for aggregate: " + aggregateName + " in Dialect: " + dialect);
        }
    //create function argument array
        List functionArgs = new ArrayList(1);
        functionArgs.add(criteriaQuery.getColumn(criteria, propertyName));

        return new StringBuffer()
          .append(function.render(functionArgs, criteriaQuery.getFactory()))
          .append(" as y").append(loc).append('_')
          .toString();


    }


}
```

and this is what the dialect looks like

```
public class ExtendedHSQLDialect extends HSQLDialect {
    public ExtendedHSQLDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("stddev", new StandardSQLFunction("stddev_pop",Hibernate.DOUBLE));
      }
}
```

Thanks ChssPly76 :)